# Visual studio code live server does not apply css styles

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

Here is the issue:

I'm encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code's Live Server extension (by ritwickdey) where it's not applying any of my CSS styles when I launch the live preview. The HTML is displayed correctly, but it seems as if my CSS is not being recognized at all. Here's what I've tried so far to resolve the issue:

I've restarted Visual Studio Code to rule out any temporary glitches.

Checked my workspace settings and file associations to ensure they are correctly configured.

Verified that Visual Studio Code is up to date, so it's not a bug in the software.

I've meticulously reviewed my code, both HTML and CSS, and have ensured that it's free of errors. I've even validated it using the W3C Markup Validation Service.

Despite all these efforts, my CSS styles are still not being applied when I use Live Server. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and what steps can I take to resolve it? Any insights or troubleshooting suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide the necessary code that shows how you connected the CSS with your HTML as well as your paths. Use the dev tools under the network tab and see if the CSS gets loaded at all or throws an error such as a 404 status code

Comment: we need a [mre]. and show **and** tell us what you see in your browser's network tab in the devtools.

Comment: To answer@starball and here is how my CSS is linked in my HTML like so <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <!-- google font family links start here -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: To answer both tacoshy and starball I have inspected my element and theres a clear issue under issues it says "this page has failed to load stylesheet URL's and under network for my styles CSS  the status does say 404 not found and initiator index.html I assume it's because that's where i linked it

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely you have not linked the css file appropriately. If it persists, have your css code within style tags within the head tag of you html code

Comment: Putting style tags within my head tag of HTML code has actually worked my CSS code is showing up now thank you so I think there must be a problem with my file path , server e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

Remove your Cache first. If you have linked properly then it will need to work properly. First check your CSS link path and secondly remove your cache.